# swagger circular dependency 1.2

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

We are using swagger-play 1.3.7 . (play framework  2.2.1 , swagger 1.2)

```
my model classes are like below

public class TypeA {
    TypeB b;
       TypeB c;
      }

public class TypeB {
    TypeA a;
        CustomBigdecimal bigdecimal;
        Map<String, Object> additionalmaps;
}

public class TypeC {
    TypeB b;
     }
```

1. how  to overcome this circular dependency in swagger 1.2 ?
2. how to convert wrapper CustomBigDecimal to BigDecimal/String ?
3. how do i represent Maps/collection ?

   any help greatly appreciated ..

   Thanks.